# UILabel text blinking when showing file progress text

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

I show file transfer progress in a label. But when the `fileprogress` data string appears than `directionstring` text blinking according to its position. How to stop this blinking of appended string?

```
directionstring = @"uploaging file";
fileprogress = transferring rate EX.(25.00 MB of 50.00 MB);
message = [message stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",fileprogress,directionstring]];
progressLabel.text = message;
```

Comment: you might be redrawing the label!! @psk

Answer (score 0):

I made an example (with timer to emulate progress), test it, text is not blinking

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *_progressLabel;
    NSInteger _percent;
}

- (void)showProgress
{
    _percent = 0;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateProgress:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateProgress:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSString *directionstring = @" uploading file";
    NSString *fileprogress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld of 100", (long)_percent++];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fileprogress, directionstring];
    _progressLabel.text = message;
}

@end
```